# Error with Insert in Datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have a usersdataTable with an "Code" column I set as PK and auto-increment "true" in MySql DB.

I want users to fill in values for first name, last name, username etc on a datagrid view but cannot enter the Code value.

I have this code for update/insert:

```
private void usersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (dgvUsers.RowCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dgvUsers.RowCount; i++)
            {
                var code = dgvUsers.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                if (code == string.Empty)
                {
                    // add users                         
                    this.usersTableAdapter.Insert(
                        dgvUsers.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                        dgvUsers.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                        dgvUsers.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                        GlobalClass.MD5Hash(dgvUsers.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
                        DateTime.Now,
                        null
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    // edit users                         
                    this.usersTableAdapter.Update(this.eko_payrollDataSet.users);
                }
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Details Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Table Structure:

```
Code      int        NN      PK   Autoincrement
firstName Varchar    NN
lastName  Varchar    NN
userName  Varchar    NN
password  varchar    NN
created   datetime   NN
modified  datetime   Null?
```

I dragged the datagridview to the form from a dataset that created a binding source. When I press the + button to add a new row and when finished entering the values, I get a `NoNullAllowedExeption for column Code` when I move the cursor to another row or attempt to add a row below this.

What do I need to do to fix this? I have not added validation code that would cause this.

I have seen the same problem I am experiencing here http://www.databaseforum.info/5/857494.aspx

Comment: Can you show the table structure for your Users Table?

Comment: @John Bartels. Edited.

Comment: Also, one other question: what line does the exception occur on? Does it occur when the Insert method is called? or when the code var is set?

Comment: Once I have added a new row and started inputting data, the exception is thrown as soon as I click on another cell on any other row, or if I try to add a new row below it.

Comment: Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610708/set-default-column-value-for-a-specific-column-in-datagridview

Comment: @Emmad Kareem. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your PK is an auto-increment column, the associated column in the DataSet should have its proper AutoIncrement and AutoIncrementSeed, if not you should be able to set them in the dataset designer.

Here is an issue similar to yours, look if you can find something useful.

[autoincrement-values-in-autogenerated](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?586585-RESOLVED-autoincrement-values-in-autogenerated-datagridview&p=3624859#post3624859)

I think there is little about your problem, can you put an example or put all the properties of the dataset/datatable and gridview.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrongly assumed the dataset would automatically update the AutoIncrement and AutoIncrementSeed properties when creating the dataset from the DB.